# Hyperledger composer playground UI fails to load when deploying a new business network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am getting a connection refused error while trying to deploy a new business network on the Hyperledger Composer playground which is running locally on the environment. The environment is behind the corporate proxy and I have setup both the proxies (http and https) in the system.

The exact error is mentioned below:

```
{"error": 
{"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"151.101.0.162","port":443}}
```

I have followed the links given below to setup the Hyperledger Fabric and the corresponding docker containers.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html

At the end of the setup, I notice that there are five docker containers running in the system -

composer, peer0.org1.example.com, orderer.example.com, ca.org1.example.com and couchdb

When I follow the developer guide and try deploying the new business  network on the Online BlueMix Composer Playground platform, it works. I was able to see the transactions, commodities and etc for the sample example application.

However, I notice the above error when I tried deploying the new business network on the local composer playground.

The development environment on which the Composer and the fabric is hosted are Ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7, node v6.11.0, npm5.0.4, docker-compose v1.13.0.

Can somebody kindly suggest a workaround / direct me to certain links to resolve this problem?

Comment: the 151 address suggests an ISP provider address and and issue trying to route. Have you got a VPN client running also?  Not sure what happens when you temporarily turn your wireless off and then try the business network deploy again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul. Yes, there is a VPN client running to connect to the machine that hosts the docker containers. Let me try with the wireless off and try deploying the business network.

Comment: I got the problem resolved by setting up the complete environment on a system that has a public facing IP address.

Comment: ok cool, thanks for the update Krishnaprasad